# Как правильно сказать во множественном числе

Tags: грамотная-речь

В верхней части боков или в верхних частях боков?

Comment: А всю фразу можно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.